# SQL Server NULL values UNDO

Tags: sql-server

I mistakenly updated the null values in my table to a string similar to an already present string. For e.g. I changed the NULL values to 'WL:5' and there were records for 'WL:5' already present. I want to change that string back to null values now, but if I update the table now, the other values which have the same name will also change. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you commited the records? Will the last modified time of the records be changed too? If so, you can revert based on last modified time.

Comment: You think that the database maintains not just all current data but all previous states as well? Do you not think that that would be a phenomenally "expensive" feature that most people would never need?

Comment: He's new, and inexperienced, and the question is valid for someone like that. So instead of this liberal "let's give attitude and vote down everyone new and vote up everyone with gold on their stats" how about we give the guy a break and do what this site was meant for: offer help? Namely, if you have access to another DB, excel, file etc with the same data with the WL:5 values (which is often the situation in test), you can use that to update everything WL:5 except those rows. Or as mehdi said below, just restore your last backup. And in the future, use rollback blocks to check first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backup file in order to recovery your data.